# Refreshing Access passthrough query

Tags: ms-access, odbc, vba

I have a passthrough query to pull my "Active Members" from an Oracle database via an ODBC passthrough query. It works great, I can link to members retrieved by the query just like I would an Access table.

My question is, will this passthrough query automatically refresh itself each time I reference it? Or should I specify the update using VBA code? Essentially, each time a user searches for a member, I need my pass through query re-run.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no auto-refresh of pass-through queries, they're just queries stored in another db's syntax.
What I usually do is create a macro deleting rows from the existing table and running the pass-through query.  If the macro introduces too much overhead, however, you could also code the steps in a function with VBA.